# How to create Column values to Row Values in the SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

How to create column values to row values in SQL Server? (SQL Server 2008 or SQL Server 2012)?

I am trying to create a Pivot format of pushing column values to row values.

```
create table #testpivot 
(
      buyer nvarchar(1000), 
      Amount money, 
      TranscDate datetime 
)
go

insert into #testpivot 
values ('Sam', 100, '2018-01-15 10:19:34.400'),
       ('Sam', 200, '2018-01-15 11:19:34.400'),
       ('Sam', 300, '2018-01-15 21:19:34.400'),
       ('Ed', 100, '2018-01-15 10:19:34.400'),
       ('Ed', 100, '2018-01-16 14:19:34.400'),
       ('Ed', 100, '2018-01-16 08:19:34.400'),
       ('Ed', 100, '2018-01-17 12:19:34.400'),
       ('Ed', 100, '2018-01-17 01:19:34.400')
go

select * from #testpivot
Go
```

Expected result:

```
Buyer       01/15/2018   01/16/2018      01/17/2018     TotalAmt
------------------------------------------------------------------
Sam             600        0                0              600                                         
Ed              100        200             200             500
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, read [MS SQL documentation - PIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot).
For your example the query looks like this

```
declare  @testpivot table( buyer nvarchar(1000), Amount money, TranscDate datetime )

insert into @testpivot values ('Sam', 100, '2018-01-15 10:19:34.400')
insert into @testpivot values ('Sam', 200, '2018-01-15 11:19:34.400')
insert into @testpivot values ('Sam', 300, '2018-01-15 21:19:34.400')
insert into @testpivot values ('Ed', 100, '2018-01-15 10:19:34.400')
insert into @testpivot values('Ed', 100, '2018-01-16 14:19:34.400')
insert into @testpivot values ('Ed', 100, '2018-01-16 08:19:34.400')
insert into @testpivot values('Ed', 100, '2018-01-17 12:19:34.400')
insert into @testpivot values('Ed', 100, '2018-01-17 01:19:34.400')

;with tbl as(
select buyer,Amount,cast(TranscDate as date) TranscDate,sum(amount) over(partition by buyer) total
from @testpivot
)
select buyer,[2018-01-15],[2018-01-16],[2018-01-17],total
from tbl
pivot (sum(amount) for TranscDate in ([2018-01-15],[2018-01-16],[2018-01-17])
) as pvt
```

In the case you cannot use hardcoded list of dated you need **dynamic SQL** to prepare and execute the query.

Comment: Thank you @Alex ..! I will. .. Just felt difficult on sum by date

Comment: MS SQL Server has some pivot functionality but I would recommend Excel (or OpenOffice spreadsheet) for better functionality.